# Insert Into n:m Table with Sequelize throws val.replace Error

Tags: sequelize.js

Ive this 3 Tables Defined

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('dict_Lang', {
    _id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    code:{
      type :DataTypes.STRING(10),
      allowNull: false},
    name_en: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull:false},
    pp_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false},
    active: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
  },{
    tableName: 'Langs'
  });
}

export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('HtmlValue', {
    _id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    categorie_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    ok_oe: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    ok_iam: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    ok_export: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    }
  }
 );
}

export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  return sequelize.define('HtmlLang', {
    titel: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(300),
      allowNull : true
    },
    text: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(4000),
      allowNull : true
    }
  }
 );
}
```

And them Associated

```
// Lang n:m Html
db.DictLang.belongsToMany(db.HtmlValue, { through: db.HtmlLang, foreignKey:'lang_id',otherKey:'html_id'});
db.HtmlValue.belongsToMany(db.DictLang, { through: db.HtmlLang, foreignKey: 'html_id',otherKey: 'lang_id'});
```

And now I want to Insert in the `HtmlLang` Table a new Row after Creating a new `HtmlValue`

```
// Creates a new HtmlValue in the DB
export function create(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.defaultDE);
  return HtmlValue.create(req.body)
  .then((html)=>{
    console.log(HtmlValue.Instance.prototype);
    return html.addDict_Lang(req.body.defaultDE);
  })
    .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

The `HtmlValue` is created fine and then it throws `val.replace Error...` .
But

```
    console.log(req.body.defaultDE); shows me { titel: 'test', text:'test2': lang_id : 73}
and
console.log(HtmlValue.Instance.prototype); shows me 
{....
 getDict_Langs: [Function],
 countDict_Langs: [Function],
 hasDict_Langs: [Function],
 hasDict_Lang: [Function],
 setDict_Langs: [Function],
 addDict_Lang: [Function],
 addDict_Langs: [Function],
 removeDict_Lang: [Function],
 removeDict_Langs: [Function],
 createDict_Lang: [Function] }
```

So the send Data is in the right Format and the Function exists and is Associated? Where could be the Error/Mistake?

**Edit1:**
As requested the output of `req.body`

```
{ user_id: 2,
  categorie_id: '1',
  defaultDE: { titel: 'Test', text: 'Test2', lang_id: 73 },
  defaultEN: { titel: 'Test', text: 'Test3', lang_id: 75 } }
```

It creates the `HtmlValue` without Error and it is in the Database.
As well in my Table `Langs` exists the `lang_id : 73`.
so with

```
html.addDict_Lang(req.body.defaultDE);
```

I want to Insert in the n:m Table.
`html` holds the `html_id` and in `req.body.defaultDE` I send the neccessary text(string),titel(string),lang_id(73<--Exists in the Lang Table).

**Edit2** For Comment `..not Plain Objects`
Ive kinda the same Structure somewhere else used.
In short

```
// Tasks n:m Keys Association
db.DictKey.belongsToMany(db.Task, { through: db.TaskKey, foreignKey:'key_id',otherKey:'task_id'});
db.Task.belongsToMany(db.DictKey, { through: db.TaskKey, foreignKey: 'task_id',otherKey: 'key_id'});
```

Doing then the same with `addAssiciation` wiht Plain Object

```
  .then((task) => {
      var groups = [];
      var size = 1000;
      for (var i = 0; i < req.body.keys.length; i += size) {
        groups.push(req.body.keys.slice(i, i + size));
      }
      _.forEach(groups, (value) => {
        return task.addDict_Keys(value);
      })
      return Task.findAll();
    })
```

And Value would be a Plain Object like

```
{ titel: 'Hello', text: 'Buenos Nachos', lang_id: 73, user_id : 2 }
```

So Plain Objects works or Iam understanding it wrong?

Comment: You are not showing the values of `req.body`

Comment: addAssociation() does not accept plain objects afaik

Comment: @felixfbecker Ive Edited my Question. I think Plain Objects work because ive used it with Plain Objects already? Did I it wrong or lies the mistake of `val.replace Error` then somewhere else?